# Sorting options in a drop down menu in Rails

Tags: sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to sort a list of users in Rails 4 based on options in a drop down menu. So I have options like "Alphabetical" or "Newest First." I created the menu, but I don't know how to get it to sort when the user selects an option. How can I make it interactive and respond to user input? Also I want it to sort automatically so that the user does not have to click "Go" or "Submit" before it starts sorting.

Answer (score 1):

If the options you are getting in Drop Down are from users model(database) you can use `.order` in the query. If not use Jquery Ajax to get them sorted without page refreshing.

for example:

```
User.all.order("asc")   # thinking you are taking all the values of user
```

**note:** If it is from user model database